# Call and load a bound data set in second form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I bound a dataset in my main form to `DataGridView` source and using this code to call and loading last added record.

```
this.phoneTableAdapter1.Fill(this.sDs1.phone);
        dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.RowCount - 1;
```

I have second form that include a save button. I cant use this code for call and show last record of `DataGridView` in main form. How to fix it? need a properties for define main form data set and use it in form2 or something else??

Comment: Try with properties as suggested by yourself.

Comment: i think its need a handle to make connection between 2 forms

Answer (score 0):

If second form opened from `Main` form, then pass main form reference to the second form through contructor

```
private MainForm _main;

public SecondForm(MainForm main)
{
    _main = main;
}
```

Then use this constructor when open second form

```
private void OpenSecondForm()
{
    SecondForm second = New SecondForm(this);
    second.Show();
}
```

This is simple example. Give some more information how you used your forms(How second form created and showed).